# How to load two seperate nodelets in the nodelet manager

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, nodelet, nodelet-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have two nodelets in separate files(one publishes sensor_msgs::Image  and the other subscribes to it) and want to load them in the nodelet manager. ROS does provide a method [here](http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet/Tutorials/Running%20a%20nodelet) but I fail to understand the details of it. Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304071/how-to-load-two-seperate-nodelets-in-the-nodelet-manager/) by [surabhi96](https://answers.ros.org/users/32900/surabhi96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2018-09-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To load your nodelets you **must** have loaded a nodelet manager first.

- Using command lines :

Load the `nodelet_manager` (you can put the name you want but make sure all your nodelets use the same manager)

`rosrun nodelet nodelet manager __name:=nodelet_manager`

Then you can load your nodelets (again replace nodelet_manager with the name you chose previously), if you have two nodelets you have to run :

```
rosrun nodelet nodelet load PACKAGE_OF_YOUR_NODELET/NODELET1 nodelet_manager
rosrun nodelet nodelet load PACKAGE_OF_YOUR_NODELET/NODELET2 nodelet_manager
```

- Using launch file :

  < node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="nodelet_manager" args="manager"/>

  < node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="NODELET1"
  args="load PACKAGE_OF_YOUR_NODELET/NODELET1 nodelet_manager">
  < /node>

  < node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="NODELET2"
  args="load PACKAGE_OF_YOUR_NODELET/NODELET2 nodelet_manager">
  < /node>

You can also set a parameter or remap some topics as in the tutorial.
I personnaly prefer to use launch files.

But always remember that the nodelet manager is mandatory here and if by mistake you load your nodelets in two different `nodelet_manager` you will lose the specificity of the nodelets and they will have the same behavior as a node.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-09-25**:
I forgot to add this useful command :

```
rosrun nodelet declared_nodelets
```

This will list all the available nodelets on your system (from [wiki section 2](http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet))